# Batch file giving invalid path error while creating an installer

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

Basically I am trying to create an installer.
I have an EXE file and I need to do the following steps through a bat file:

1. create a folder at C:\Data
2. Copy a file in C.\Data
3. Create a folder inside C:\Program Files
4. Copy exe file in C:\Program Files\My Project Folder
5. Create shortcut to exe on Desktop

My code is as follows:

```
@echo off
if not exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\MyFolder" mkdir %PROGRAMFILES%\MyFolder
if not exist "C:\Data" mkdir C:\Data
copy /q /y ".\MyFile.exe" "%PROGRAMFILES%\MyFolder\MyFile.exe"
copy /q /y ".\MyFileDb.db" "C:\Data\MyFileDb.db"
```

The problem is that it shows "**invalid path**" error and says 0 files copied for **MyFolder**. However, it successfully creates **Data** folder and copies **MyFileDb.db** inside it.

Second problem is that I cannot figure out how to execute the Step 5 of my problem statement.

Comment: Look at where you put quotes, then look at where you didn't put quotes. Remember that if a path has spaces, then you _have_ to surround it with quotes.

Comment: Are you running the script As Administrator? _The `Program Files` directory is protected from normal users!_ As a side note, there are things which I would consider wrong with lines `2`, `3` ,`4` and `5`.

Comment: `If Not Exist "%ProgramFiles%\MyFolder\" MD "%ProgramFiles%\MyFolder"`, `If Not Exist "C:\Data\" MD "C:\Data"`, `Copy /Y "MyFile.exe" "%ProgramFiles%\MyFolder"`, `Copy /Y "MyFileDb.db" "C:\Data"`. However you could use `XCopy` which, if used correctly, would create non existing directories as part of its copying process, _thus removing two of those four lines completely_.

Comment: As previously mentioned, in order for you to copy a file to the Program Files directory, the script needs to run with elevated privileges.  When that happens, the current working directory becomes the SYSTEM32 directory so your executable and database file are no longer in the current working directory. Assuming the batch file is in the same directory as the two files you need to copy, you can do a change directory back to that folder or you can also use the PUSHD command.  `CD /D %~dp0` or `pushd %~dp0`.

Comment: ...or for an extra degree of safety you may be able to use `Copy /Y "%~dp0MyFile.exe" "%ProgramFiles%\MyFolder"`, `Copy /Y "%~dp0MyFileDb.db" "C:\Data"`, which will pick up the files from the running batch file's own directory.

Comment: As for creating the shortcut, you should research and attempt it first before asking the question. This site is designed to help you to fix your code, not to provide it for you. Also, as you should be aware, there is more than one Desktop location on Windows, _and depending upon the Windows version and method used, may be accessed differently_; which one do you want to create a shortcut on?

Answer (score 0):

1. ***MSI***: I would use a proper MSI deployment tool. [**Here are some of the major ones**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130).

   - For something this simple I think the free version of [**Advanced Installer**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) would work properly. It should be very simple. Maybe check the [help portal](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29130) and [the videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhybAX-2L54zAc8PrPfSX7JCAe12VVFii).
   - Then there is always [**WiX**](https://www.wixtoolset.org) which is free and open source, but [there is a learning curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).
   - [The Visual Studio Installer projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) do work for simple things, but [do not scale well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130). Free.
2. ***Non-MSI***: You can also use [non-MSI deployment technologies](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_nonmsi.htm) such as [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.htm) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/).
3. ***Self-Extraction Tools***: Some recommend self-extracting archives.

   - [I am very skeptical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757086/error-creating-a-7-zip-installer-package/51757384#51757384) - essentially for **practical-**, **runtime dependency-** and **security-reasons**.
   - [Combine exe and msi file in one installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125498/combine-exe-and-msi-file-in-one-installer/52126911#52126911)

---

***Some Further Links***:

- ***RoboCopy.exe***: [How do I compare two folders recursively and generate a list of files and folders that are different?](https://superuser.com/questions/748069/how-do-i-compare-two-folders-recursively-and-generate-a-list-of-files-and-folder) A practical sample of using the newer RoboCopy.exe to do the copying.