# Windows MSI installer VS xcopy

Tags: installation, windows-installer, updates, deploying

I'm working with a pretty old application that went through a series of updates over the decades and each time it was redeployed the developers used MSI projects to install the updated files. When it came time to deploy my update I did the same thing. However the MSI installer is very annoying to build and install with. I would like to just build a script that uses xcopy to move updated files from a disk to the target directory. Is there a benefit I would lose by not using an MSI installer?

Comment: I have the following answer with some details on MSI benefits: [How to create Windows Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130). Additionally, what tool are you using? [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58822251/129130) for some links to specific tools and also descriptions of limitations of VS Installer Projects (if that is what you are using).

Comment: And for the record, the free tool with a hefty learning curve if you don't know MSI: [WiX quick start tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130). For simple stuff Advanced Installer has a free version: [please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53144590/129130).